# Service "Finsky" loops indefinitely scheduling jobs and using large amounts of data traffic

Tags: google-play-store

Connected with ADB to a work device I manage, I see logcat with tag "Finsky" looping multiple times per second scheduling jobs and completing it. The logcat output albeit spammy is not a problem in itself, but I have a strong suspicion this is also what causes massive metered data usage for the Google Play Store app.

Attached is a screenshot where a brand new SIM card has been connected for about 10 minutes. Google Play Store has consumed 36 MB of data.

We have a fleet of devices where this one is included, managed by Mobile Iron, where this is a pattern that repeats itself. By the end of the month, Google Play Store has consumed 20-30 GB of data on each device.

The log segment that is repeating looks like this in logcat:

```
2022-02-23 15:57:14.698 20819-20963/? I/Finsky: [56] qla.apply(77): SCH: Scheduling 0 system job(s)
2022-02-23 15:57:14.699 20819-21030/? I/Finsky: [87] kmg.D(6): IQ: Pruning inactive install requests
2022-02-23 15:57:14.699 20819-21030/? I/Finsky: [87] kmg.D(45): IQ: No matching installs to run for jobs: []
2022-02-23 15:57:14.700 20819-21030/? I/Finsky: [87] qlw.r(4): SCH: jobFinished: 3-123627655. TimeElapsed: 17ms.
2022-02-23 15:57:14.702 20819-20819/? I/Finsky: [2] qmf.accept(49): SCH: Job 3-123627659 starting
2022-02-23 15:57:14.702 20819-20819/? I/Finsky: [2] InstallQueuePhoneskyJob.g(2): IQ::IQPJ: Handling expired job 123627659
2022-02-23 15:57:14.704 20819-21030/? I/Finsky: [87] khz.apply(79): IQ: Creating job 123627661, for (REQ_GEARHEAD_PROJECTION_OFF, IGNORE_HOLDOFF=true, NETWORK=UNMETERED, PROVISIONING_STATE=PROVISIONED, TIME=[2021-12-17T17:00:00Z-2021-12-18T05:00:00Z])
2022-02-23 15:57:14.704 20819-21030/? I/Finsky: [87] kmg.x(9): IQ: Bulk scheduling created jobs
2022-02-23 15:57:14.708 20819-20955/? I/Finsky: [49] qlq.accept(70): SCH: Scheduling phonesky job Id: 3-123627661, CT: 1645628234705, Constraints: [{ L: 0, D: 0, C: 1, I: 1, N: 2 }, { L: 0, D: 0, C: 1, I: 1, N: 0 }]
2022-02-23 15:57:14.720 20819-20955/? I/Finsky: [49] qla.apply(77): SCH: Scheduling 0 system job(s)
2022-02-23 15:57:14.722 20819-21030/? I/Finsky: [87] kmg.D(6): IQ: Pruning inactive install requests
2022-02-23 15:57:14.723 20819-21030/? I/Finsky: [87] kmg.D(45): IQ: No matching installs to run for jobs: []
2022-02-23 15:57:14.723 20819-21030/? I/Finsky: [87] qlw.r(4): SCH: jobFinished: 3-123627656. TimeElapsed: 40ms.
```

If I filter by "Scheduling phonesky job" I get like multiple entries per second, in the span of 90 seconds I got 571 hits in logcat which amounts to ~6.3 jobs per second.

This cannot possibly be normal?

I suspect Mobile Iron to have a part in this but I cannot see evidence of Mobile Iron in the logs (I've searched for package `com.mobileiron.anyware.android`). Reason is that this coincides with Mobile Iron not being able to automatically update apps from Play Store. Our apps remain stuck at older versions even when newer versions are available on Play Store. We've had 20-30 mails back and forth with Mobile Iron support without them being able to help us.

1. Anyone have any idea why this amount of jobs are scheduled?
2. Who is repsonsible for scheduling these jobs?
3. How can I verify that it's these jobs that cause data traffic?
4. Any other tips on how I can continue debugging this issue is appreciated

[image: Play store data usage after 10 mins]